# How to solve this : 'Running android lint' issue

Tags: android, eclipse, nullpointerexception, android-lint

In any activity of my project, if i do some changes and then save that activity i got the message "Running android lint has encountered a problem."

This is the my error log :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AdtUtils.workspacePathToFile(AdtUtils.java:466)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.lint.EclipseLintClient.getClassPath(EclipseLintClient.java:753)
at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintClient.getJavaClassFolders(LintClient.java:198)
at com.android.tools.lint.detector.api.Project.getJavaClassFolders(Project.java:270)
at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.checkIndividualClassFiles(LintDriver.java:977)
at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.checkClasses(LintDriver.java:920)
at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.runFileDetectors(LintDriver.java:785)
at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.checkProject(LintDriver.java:661)
at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.analyze(LintDriver.java:288)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.lint.LintJob.run(LintJob.java:151)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)\
```

I don't to know how to solve this.

Comment: Have you refreshed your project ? It is likely to be caused by eclipse keeping a reference on a non-existent file

Comment: @Geoffroy yeah but problem remains the same..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

However, the root cause here is some sort of invalid project definition -- one or more of the class path entries are pointing to a resource which can't be opened; for example, you might have a classpath reference which is relative to a class path variable, and the class path variable is no longer pointing to an absolute location.

The above CL will simply make sure that lint doesn't throw an exception in this scenario, but it won't be able to do actually include the given reference.

You'll want to look at the project properties dialog and make sure all the build paths and resources are correct -- and that's the workaround until this issue is integrated

Answer (score 25):

The following steps helped me to solve the same issue.

1. On `My Project -> Context Menu -> Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties`
2. Changing to latest version in **AndroidManifest.xml**

   ```
   android:targetSdkVersion="21"
   ```

Maybe just one of them is enough :).

Comment: I just do the 1) and this fix the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

In **`Window > Preferences > Android > Lint Error Checking`**; Uncheck **"When saving files check for errors".**

I hope it will helps you

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me was to open the "appcompat_v7" project on my Package explorer. I had closed it before and forgot to open so I got the same problem as OP. Now it's all fixed

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution, just tested it.

Go to `Project properties -> Java` and set compiler change Compiler compliance level: to 1.7.

If this is not working then try `Project properties -> Android` switch from what ever it is using to android 4.4.2.

Answer (score 3):

In my particular case, the problem was caused by conflicting key bindings.

Check .metadata/.log in your project folder for hints.

Answer (score 1):

Why this Error?

It seems that its something related to appcompat_v7 library that we have in our package Explorer. If you are working with API (targetSdkVersion) level 21 you would not face this issue.

For Mac OS X Operating System :

Go to Menu : Eclipse -> Preferences -> Android -> Lint Error Checking and Un-Check : "When saving files, check for errors"

For Windows Operating System :

Go to Menu : Window -> Preferences -> Android -> Lint Error Checking and Un-Check : "When saving files, check for errors"

You may find this post helpful : http://code2care.org/pages/solution-running-android-lint-has-encountered-a-problem-nullpointerexception-error/