# Running Android Lint has encountered a... Failed. java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, lint

I just added Google Play Service Library to my project and when I am making a modification in one of my project files I am keep getting an error dialog from eclipse:

> 'Running Android Lint' has encountered a problem. Failed.

So, I enabled Error Log (Window -> Show View -> Error Log) tab and I found a warning and an error line:

**Error:
Failed: com.android.ide.eclipse.adt**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.tools.lint.checks.ApiDetector$ApiVisitor.checkField(ApiDetector.java:1416)
    at com.android.tools.lint.checks.ApiDetector$ApiVisitor.visitSelect(ApiDetector.java:1277)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.JavaVisitor$DispatchVisitor.visitSelect(JavaVisitor.java:904)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.JavaVisitor$DelegatingJavaVisitor.visitSelect(JavaVisitor.java:1147)
    at lombok.ast.Select.accept(Select.java:91)
    at lombok.ast.MethodInvocation.accept(MethodInvocation.java:121)
    at lombok.ast.ExpressionStatement.accept(ExpressionStatement.java:63)
    at lombok.ast.Block.accept(Block.java:106)
    at lombok.ast.MethodDeclaration.accept(MethodDeclaration.java:240)
    at lombok.ast.NormalTypeBody.accept(NormalTypeBody.java:57)
    at lombok.ast.ClassDeclaration.accept(ClassDeclaration.java:239)
    at lombok.ast.CompilationUnit.accept(CompilationUnit.java:83)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.JavaVisitor.visitFile(JavaVisitor.java:219)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.checkIndividualJavaFiles(LintDriver.java:1624)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.runFileDetectors(LintDriver.java:993)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.checkProject(LintDriver.java:869)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.analyze(LintDriver.java:442)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.analyze(LintDriver.java:363)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.lint.LintJob.run(LintJob.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

**and a Warning:
Fatal Error: No API database found at null**

```
An exception stack trace is not available.
```

My application is working, but it is annoying to close the dialog each time I make an edit and save.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to solve this : 'Running android lint' issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12243762/how-to-solve-this-running-android-lint-issue)

Answer (score 4):

This is a workaround (not exactly the solution). In **Window > Preferences > Android > Lint Error Checking**, uncheck "When saving files check for errors".

**EDIT**:

Please use the above steps only if you don't care about linting your code. These steps are for turning off Lint checking, not correcting the reported lint errors.

Comment: Ignoring errors (in this case, a corrupted workspace) is not even close to a solution. I wouldn't even call it a workaround.

Comment: It is precisely a workaround and he was upfront about it not being a solution. Not sure how your comment got 8 upvotes.

Comment: I agree it's not even a workaround, the question is how to run lint without given erro, not how to disable lint

Answer (score -3):

I would suggest for you to check on the warnings on your project. Resolving them one by one may get rid of the startup error.