# Running android lint

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a issue after update the Java SDK and Android SDK. My Eclipse says

> Running Android Lint" has encountered a problem. Details: Failed java.lang.NullPointerException

There is not any error in the IDE, only some warnings. So then, when i try to run any application, the IDE show me a panel with this text:

> Unable to execute dex: GC overhead limit exceeded GC overhead limit
>   exceeded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/101120/ last week. Will be included in 23.0.3 (Android SDK Tools).

Source: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=73002

Answer (score 1):

The new Android SDK seems to have many bugs in it.

For starters, the upgrade process didn't work, so many of us had to uninstall the previously perfect ADT, and install a new one, which happened to use an older version of Eclipse for some reason.

I have been receiving the above error since the upgrade.

I have also had Eclipse hang on me while loading, many times with this new old version.

---

The solution in my case has just been to CTRL-ALT-DEL kill the Eclipse process, and start it up again.

Some of the solutions on these older questions may also help:

- [Constant 'Running Android Lint' Failed, nullpointerexception popping up in Eclipse (but doesn't seem to be my code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11855352/constant-running-android-lint-failed-nullpointerexception-popping-up-in-eclip?rq=1)
- [Running Android Lint has encountered a... Failed. java.lang.NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876763/running-android-lint-has-encountered-a-failed-java-lang-nullpointerexception?rq=1)

Comment: Well, my solution has been make another folder and import the projects to that workbench. Thanks!