# running android lint error on saving file

Tags: java, android, eclipse, exception, lint

after i update my adt *22.1* to *22.6.2*, 
every time i save my `java or xml` file, *eclipse* will give an error on a dialouge box, says 
*"Running android lint problem"* has encountered a problem, and has two button 
ok and details
in details button it says `java null pointer exception`.
I have no idea , that whats the solution.
I update all packages in my sdk.
I don't understand that its adt's 22.6.2 problem or any other problem
I tried every thing but not reach through the solution.
waiting for solution.

Answer (score 0):

please try this :

the root cause here is some sort of invalid project definition -- one or more of the class path entries are pointing to a resource which can't be opened; for example, you might have a classpath reference which is relative to a class path variable, and the class path variable is no longer pointing to an absolute location.

The above CL will simply make sure that lint doesn't throw an exception in this scenario, but it won't be able to do actually include the given reference.

You'll want to look at the project properties dialog and make sure all the build paths and resources are correct -- and that's the workaround until this issue is integrated

reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/12243826/1332870

Comment: bro the problem occurs in every project, if there is still a issue releted to classpath location, plz tell me how to point class path location.

Comment: what is your java version 1.5/6/7?

Comment: can you put screenshot please

Comment: i have jdk1.8 and jre8.