# Android Lint - What to do with it?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-lint

I installed an add-on (UML Lab Class Diagram Editor) from the Eclipse MarketPlace.
Since then I get errors about Android Lint when my eclipse starts:

```
Android Lint has encountered a problem.
Failed
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

.

```
Android Lint has encountered a problem.
An internal error occurred during: "Running Android Lint".
com/android/ide/common/sdk/SdkVersionInfo
```

Then Lint stops working and I can't access Window -> Run Android Lint -> ...
I've never really used it intentionally, some people say they do without it. Though it seems useful and i'd prefer see it working.

Not the first time I got problems with Lint, everytime you change a bit your environnement, Android ADT seems to have problems.
Im still new on Eclipse/Android ADT and I might have misused it.

---

What's Android Lint?
*The Android lint tool is a static code analysis tool that checks your Android project source files for potential bugs and optimization improvements for correctness, security, performance, usability, accessibility, and internationalization.*
from http://developer.android.com/tools/help/lint.html

---

Is Android Lint that useful? Is it normal it crashes so often when you install add-ons/modify your environnement? Whats the good practice to keep it working?

Comment: I got the same error so I disabled it. can't say if it's useful or not since it never worked for me :).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25277746/139985